# Mobile Web App login and show data in tables using jquery ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am creating an app that let's students login and show the module they have registered in styled tables. I have done the server side login and it does respond in JSON format but I have little knowledge in Ajax and jQuery so I am not sure how to use the JSON keys as values of the variables in jquery.

This is is what I have on the server side and currently responds in JSON upon a successful or failed login and does return student info + modules (to be added to the SQL Query) :

```
<?php
ob_flush();
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$server = "sqlserveraddress\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"sa",     "PWD"=>"sqlpassword" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo );
$username=$_POST["sid"]; 
$password1= sha1($_POST["password"]);

$sql = "SELECT name, sid, dob FROM STUDENTS where sid = '$username' and `     `password='$password1'";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options);
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

$dob = $row['dob'];
$name = $row['name'];

if ($row_count == 1) 
{
$return = array('name' => $name,'dob' => $dob, 'status' => 'success' );
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($return);
}

else
{
$return = array('status' => 'fail');
echo "Student ID or password is wrong!!!";
}


}
?>
```

This is my login.js which at the moment posts the data to the php and I am presented with output of the json for example:

{
"name":"Jams Matts                     ","dob":"04-02-1991","status":"success"
}

login.js:

```
$.post("",{ sid: sid, password:password});
$.ajax({
type       : "POST",
url        : "http://serverip/login.php",
crossDomain: true,
beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
data       : {sid : $("#sid").val(), password : $("#passord").val()},
dataType   : 'json',
success    : function(response) {
    //console.error(JSON.stringify(response));
    alert('Works!');
},
error      : function() {
    //console.error("error");
    alert('Now working!');                  
}
});
```

so now I want to have the user redirected to the home page where he/she can see their modules (depending on how many they have) and for now, Welcome $name (that is returned by json I suppose)

and this is my index.html(using PhoneGap):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and     height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse    /CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-    scale=1,         maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width,     height=device-height,     target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com    /ajax/libs    /jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>MyGrade</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">&nbsp;</p>
            <div class="loginform-in">
<h1>User Login</h1>
<div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
<fieldset>
<form action="http://serverIP/index.php" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li> <label for="name">SID </label>
        <input type="text" size="30"  name="sid" id="sid"  /></li>
        <li> <label for="name">Password</label>
        <input type="password" size="30"  name="password"     id="password"      /></li>
        <li> <label></label>
        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login"         class="loginbutton" ></li>
    </ul>
     </form>    
</fieldset>
</div>


            <p class="event received">&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code for login? I think this is not a right way to do login with jquery ,ajax, php .. you should control that by $_SESSION .. so pass sid and password to php  and just check if user exists and active or not .. if user exists open $_SESSION and redirect by js using window.location.href .. in php check if isset $_SESSION echo user data

Comment: the problem is at the moment, my form is posting to the php and jot the js. How can I do that?